# URL Scheme in an already-open app

Tags: ios, xcode, parameter-passing, url-scheme

I'm developing an app which must be related to another app in this way:

1. The first app have a button that, through a URL Scheme, opens the second app and pass two parameters (user and password).
2. The second app verifies those parameters and give access if they're Ok.

The system works well if second app is not opened, but if the second app is already open (in background) and is called from the first app with different user and password, doesn't work (the URL Scheme method in AppDelegate is only called once, of course).

Is there any way to allow second app to get new paramenters even is already-open?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **2** cases when your second app is called by another app.

In these 2 cases, your second app will receive a `NSURL` object.

You have to implement 2 method in your `AppDelegate.m` (**HERE #1**, **HERE #2**)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//.......
//.......

NSURL *url = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
if (url)
{
   //OK, it means that app is being called via URL Schema
   //..... HERE #1
}

//.......
//.......
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
     //............... HERE #2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In UIApplicationDelegate there's

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

Asks the delegate to open a resource identified by URL.
```

According to the docs, this method is called after application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: when the latter method returns YES. If your app is already open, only this method is called.

> Your implementation of this method should open the specified URL and
>   update its user interface accordingly. If your app had to be launched
>   to open the URL, the app calls the
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods first, followed by
>   this method. The return values of those methods can be used to prevent
>   this method from being called. (If the app is already running, only
>   this method is called.)